# how to use Selenium::WebDriver::Element#attribute('value')

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, bdd, capybara

I have been getting 
`Selenium::WebDriver::Element#value is deprecated, please use Selenium::WebDriver::Element#attribute('value')` warning.

I am getting this warning message only for 
`page.find(:xpath, "//select").value.should == "general"`.

Can any one tell me how to use `attribute('value')` instead?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you use capybara?

Got the same message myself, but capybara currently still accesses the value directly as seen in https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/selenium/node.rb#L16

I will send them a fix. Should be done in future versions hopefully